# Tkinter - How to increase label value by clicking button?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-button, tkinter-label

By clicking the <kbd>Start</kbd> button, the value on label must be increased by 3 every 500 milliseconds until I destroy the window,
but the value is stuck on 0.

```
from tkinter import *

def start(value):
    value+=3
    label['text']=str(value)
    if True:
        root.after(500, start, value)
def stop():
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("420x250")
value = 0

label = Label(root, background="pink", width=20, height=2, text = str(value))
label.pack(anchor=W, pady=5)
btn1 = Button(root, text="Start", width=6, height=2, command=start).pack(
            side=LEFT, anchor=NW, padx=2, pady=2)
btn2 = Button(root, text="Stop", width=6, height=2, command=stop).pack(
            side=LEFT, anchor=NW, pady=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A Button's `command=` function will be called with *no parameters* when the Button is clicked - but yours requires a `value` parameter, so the call fails.  (There should be an error message telling you about this!). You need to access `value` in some other way - as a global variable, perhaps.

Comment: You can set the default value of `value` argument to zero, like  `def start(value=0)`.  Moreover you need to make sure that `start()` is executed only once, otherwise there may be more than one *`after`* loop created.

Comment: @Jose. Your code is working. I don't see no issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the `command=start` for the <kbd>Start</kbd> button isn't passing it the parameter the `start()` function expects. That could be fixed by removing the parameter from the function's definition and modifying it to directly access the `global` variable.

However I think it would be better in this case to use a tkinter's "Variable Classes" to do things given what else it looks like what you're trying to do. (See [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) for a little documentation.) One of the most useful features they have is that they can be used in many widgets (such as `Label`s) *instead* of supplying a static text string. When that's done, the widget's display of the variable's value will *automatically* get update itself whenever the value of `tkinter.Variable` changes.

Below is example code showing how to use them which also makes use of an additional `tkinter.Variable` to hold the value of a boolean flag the controls whether the updating is enabled. I also added a third `Button` to quit since I changed what the <kbd>Stop</kbd> button does in your code.

```
from tkinter import *

def start():
    incflag_var.set(True)
    inc_value()  # Start incrementing.

def inc_value():
    value_var.set(value_var.get() + 3)  # Will auto update label.

    if incflag_var.get():
        root.after(500, inc_value)

def stop():
    incflag_var.set(False)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("420x250")

value_var = IntVar(value=0)
incflag_var = BooleanVar(value=False)

label = Label(root, background="pink", width=20, height=2, textvariable=value_var)
label.pack(anchor=W, pady=5)
Button(root, text="Start", width=6, height=2, command=start).pack(
            side=LEFT, anchor=NW, padx=2, pady=2)
Button(root, text="Stop", width=6, height=2, command=stop).pack(
            side=LEFT, anchor=NW, pady=2)
Button(root, text="Quit", width=6, height=2, command=root.quit).pack(
            side=LEFT, anchor=NW, pady=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `textvariable=value_var` for `label`? Then you don't need to call `label['text'] = str(value)` inside `inc_value()`.  Also it is better to execute `inc_value()` only when `incflag_var` is set to `False`, otherwise there may be more than one *after loop* executed when `Start` button is clicked more than once.

Comment: @acw1668: Yeah, realized the first thing myself and have modified my answer accordingly. Not worried about multiple after loops running so haven't bothered since I don't think it's that likely an issue.

Comment: I discovered recently that `text` can "natively" support integers btw so that conversion wouldn't be necessary, it could be `label["text"] = value` @acw1668

Comment: in fact, it would be possible to do `label["text"] += 3`

Comment: @Matiiss: You don't need to update the label's `"text"` value when using an `IntVar`.

Comment: I'm saying that you don't need an `IntVar` in the first place

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out `tkinter.Label` can support `int`eger values too, so the way you can do incrementing is by simply using `label["text"] += 3` if the starting `text` of the label is an `int`eger (or `float` probably works too).

You also need to not let it create multiple `after` "loops" so setting some flags and checking those also should be added, the way I implemented it is by creating an attribute for that same label that tells whether it has started counting and if it hasn't then start.

```py
import tkinter as tk


def start():
    if not getattr(label, "counting", False):
        update()
    label.counting = True


def stop():
    root.destroy()


def update():
    label["text"] += 3
    root.after(500, update)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("420x250")

label = tk.Label(root, background="pink", width=20, height=2, text=0)
label.pack(anchor="w", pady=5)
tk.Button(root, text="Start", width=6, height=2, command=start).pack(
    side="left", anchor="nw", padx=2, pady=2
)
tk.Button(root, text="Stop", width=6, height=2, command=stop).pack(
    side="left", anchor="nw", pady=2
)

root.mainloop()
```

Also note that there is no point in assigning the returned values of `pack` (or `grid` or `place`) to a variable, you can just simply create buttons without those variables, `label` on the other hand of course needs to be referenced so it's properly made for that.

Also:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: If there's a separate "incrementing" flag with only one way to turn it on and off, you don't need to worry about multiple `after` "loops".

Answer (score 0):

> the value on label must be increased by 3 every 500 milliseconds until
> I destroy the window, but the value is stuck on 0.

The problem can be fix.

You need to declare variable. then add `global` in `start` function. Remove value in parameter `root.after`.

Change this:

```
def start(value):
    value+=3
    label['text']=str(value)
    if True:
        root.after(500, start, value)
```

to:

```
value = 0
def start():
    global value
    value+=3
    label['text']= value 
    if True:
        root.after(500, start)
```